# How to set programmatically QWidget in the center of the window in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I have such code on Qt.

```
wdgCenter = new QWidget(wdgMain);
wdgCenter->move(wdgCenter->parentWidget()->geometry().center());
wdgCenter->resize(QSize(170, 115));

welcomeLbl = new QLabel("Welcome to the Notes. Log in first.", wdgCenter);
welcomeLbl->setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(0, 0), QSize(175, 20)));

loginLbl = new QLabel("Login", wdgCenter);
loginLbl->setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(0, 30), QSize(50, 20)));

pswdLbl = new QLabel("Password", wdgCenter);
pswdLbl->setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(0, 60), QSize(50, 20)));

loginLine = new QLineEdit (wdgCenter);
loginLine->setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(60, 30), QSize(110, 20)));

passwordLine = new QLineEdit (wdgCenter);
passwordLine->setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(60, 60), QSize(110, 20)));

logInBtn = new QPushButton ("Log In", wdgCenter);
logInBtn->setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(0, 90), QSize(50, 25)));

createBtn = new QPushButton ("Create", wdgCenter);
createBtn->setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(60, 90), QSize(50, 25)));
```

The result you can see below on the first picture.

[image: default picture]

I want to move my `wdgCenter` to the center of the window. I tried `QGridLayout` like this below.

```
QGridLayout* gLayout = new QGridLayout(wdgMain);

gLayout->addWidget( welcomeLbl );
gLayout->setAlignment(welcomeLbl,Qt::AlignHCenter);
gLayout->addWidget( loginLbl, 1, 0  );
gLayout->setAlignment(loginLbl,Qt::AlignHCenter);
gLayout->addWidget( pswdLbl, 2, 0 );
gLayout->setAlignment(pswdLbl,Qt::AlignHCenter);
gLayout->addWidget( loginLine, 1, 1 );
gLayout->setAlignment(loginLine,Qt::AlignHCenter);
gLayout->addWidget( passwordLine, 2, 1 );
gLayout->setAlignment(passwordLine,Qt::AlignHCenter);
gLayout->addWidget( logInBtn, 3, 0 );
gLayout->setAlignment(logInBtn,Qt::AlignHCenter);
gLayout->addWidget( createBtn, 3, 1 );
gLayout->setAlignment(createBtn,Qt::AlignHCenter);
```

And the result you can see on the next picture below.

[image]

I also tried `QHBoxLayout` and `QHBoxLayout` but they just draw me my objects in on row or in one column.

In Qt Designer I did this with vertical and horizontal spacers like this:

[image]

But I need to do this programmatically.

How to set my `wdgCenter` to The center?

Comment: Rebuild the same layout structure, using spacings. Or just create a subwidget, set its size hints to Minimum or Fixed, and put it in any layout (QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, etc.) with a center alignment.

Comment: @peppe, can you show me example on two labels, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way would be designing the UI using Qt Designer and let it generate the source code. Auto-generated source code for the UI is in a `.h` file called `ui_<your class name>.h`, for example: `ui_mainwindow.h`. This file is included automatically in `<your class name>.cpp` file, so you can find it there.

The Qt Designer overview:

[image]

Result:

[image]